# Selenium Explicit wait usage in C#

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver

Earlier i used to use Expected Conditions class to wait for an element to display.

Since ExpectedConditions class is obselete now, I am using the below piece of code to specify my webdriver to wait for 30 seconds beforing throwing no such element exception. Is this code valid and meaningful? If not, please suggest the usage.

```
WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
 wait.Until(d=>driver.FindElement(By.ID("")).Displayed);
```

Comment: Look at the code that implements `ExpectedConditions`... what does it check for? Is it just `.Displayed`? Hint: no.

Comment: That is pretty much how you would use explicit waits, although a 30 second limit is  quite high. Are you having any issues?

Comment: WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
 wait.Until(d=>driver.FindElement(By.ID("")).Displayed);

I cannot wait until an element is Clickable using the above piece of code. looks like I will have to go with SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.

Answer (score 3):

Go to "NuGet package manager" and install DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers and then you will be able to use wait condition like, wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.UrlContains(URL));